# Instagram OAuth site not working any more

Tags: authentication, oauth, instagram

I have a Windows Phone application and I am using the Instagram authentication. Everything worked fine Long time until a fe days ago. The Login page is not loading any more in the Webbrowser (in app browser) but still works in the real browser.

I am using this link:

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code

It works fine on my PC and in the normal Windows Phone browser. But it doesn't load any more in the in app Webbrowser, it just stays blank. You know why?
Even when I navigate to www.instagram.com in the in-app bwebbrowser object and then tap on Login, it doesn't load. It loads a blank White page.

I really need help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instagram helped me :)

In Windows Phone 8 webbrowser control you must enable scripts. Just set this property to True and it works again :)

```
IsScriptEnabled="True"
```

In Windows Phone 8.1 you don't have to do that. I can confirm both :)

Thanks Instagram for your help!

Comment: How did you contact Instagram?  I have a similar problem in a desktop application using the IE browser component.  Javascript is enabled by default there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418323/history-js-javascript-error-preventing-login-authentication-with-ie-browser-comp

Comment: Go to your Instagram API site where you have your client. Then you can click on "Report Issue". This way they answered the same day :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they have performed an update to their systems over the past few days which causes Javascript errors to appear in the OAUTH window under IE8. Don't really know anything about Windows Phone but it could be related.

This is something that one of my colleagues has reported today so we are waiting to see what their response is.

Kev.

Comment: How do you contact Instagram?  I have a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418323/history-js-javascript-error-preventing-login-authentication-with-ie-browser-comp